# TFS building incorrect version of project on build server but builds correct version locally

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, wix, build-process

My issue is **"When I build a project on my build server, it does not get the correct version. But when I build it locally the project locally it does get the correct version"**

How do I know this? ...On the build server when I open the file, the contents are not what they should be, as they are in TFS.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and WIX 3.8. On my build servers I have wix 3.8.

I have a WIX installer (INSTALLER XYZ) which **references project A.**
Project A has a **configuration.config** file inside it. The **configuration.config** file is essential for the MSI to work. When I build the "installer XYZ" locally and install it everything works fine.

When I run a build (on the build server) it builds "installer XYZ" and produces a .msi file. When I install the .msi file I get an error. The install fails.
After investigating and I have found out that when I build on the build server, the "installer XYZ" which references Project A **configuration.config** file is using an older version of this file and not the latest version. I don't understand why this is happening.

If I use the .msi which was built locally, it installs fine but when I use the .msi which was built on the build server, it does not install.

Let me explain a few things that I have tried...

1. The msi's are exactly the same except for this **configuration.config** file. I have used the tools LessMsi and Orca to examine the .msi's.
2. When I build the project on the build server, I have checked the **configuration.config** file and it is different the one in **Project A**
3. **I have got the latest from TFS before building. I have got specific and overwritten all the files from TFS before building.**
4. I have expanded project A and right clicked on **configuration.config** file and selected properties. The property "COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY" is set to COPY ALWAYS".
5. My WIX installer is harvesting the files correctly. I have recreated my .WXS file and referenced project A correctly using `Source="$(var.Connectors.AgentService.TargetDir)"`
6. On my build server I have deleted all workspaces.
7. I have deleted all work spaces that my build service account created.
8. My build definition "Clean Workspace" is set to "All"
9. I have restarted my computer and the build server

To conclude, I know what the issue is but I'm not sure what's causing it... Can anybody advise?

#### Update 22.05.2014

So I've investigated further,

I have another project in the same solution called Project.B
Project.B also has a **configuration.config** file.

What seems to be happening is that the **configuration.config** file from Project B is being built. I tested this by changing the contents of project.B **configuration.config** file and rebuilding it. However, my WIX installer references project A **configuration.config** file.
It seems that the build process is getting confused between the two projects in the same solution.

Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Comment: So, point #2. Where does the "different one" come from? Do a ctrl+f on build server to search where the old one is located at.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa From TFS. Its getting a older version of that file. For example if the file is at version 4 now, the build server still gets version 1. But when I build locally (not on build server) it gets version 4.

Comment: That sounds interesting. So essentially, just to confirm: this issue has nothing to do with WiX? It's completely TFS problem?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS build, all files are copied into one bin folder. However, Visual Studio has "bin folder per project" structure.

This would explain why your configuration.config is overridden by projectB. They are all copied into same folder.

You can split the folder structure again, by adding this property to your build definition:

[image]

Notice the flag `/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true`

Comment: What do you mean? Did the given solution not work for you? Or are you saying that this works, but it's not really the solution you'd like to have?

Comment: It doesn't answer my initial question of "Does anybody know why this could be happening?" nevertheless, your proposal does work.

Comment: Well, I already answered WHY it happens. It happens because TFS builds everything in to one bin folder, and overrides happen. If you're wondering WHY they did it like that, I can't comment their choices, but it seems like a poor choice from their side. They probably did not consider WiX being built on TFS Build - I've had personally many bugs with Wix+TFS Build(harvested files locked, wix build order incorrect, bin folder issue, ...).

Comment: If you consider what TFS BUild has to do: it has to validate if solution successfully compiles - it does not have to generate "valid" installer. Thus, it really doesn't matter if overrides in "bin" folder happen.

Comment: Thanks. I can't make your response as a answer because I have a current reputation of '1' and you need a minimum rep of '15'.